# Consumers in RabbitMQ DirectMessageListenerContainer - Memory Impact in Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, spring-amqp

I have a scenario where i am creating the predefined consumers for queues in `DirectMessageListenerContainer` bean as follows:

```
@Bean
public DirectMessageListenerContainer directMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory conn, DynamicTenantListenerCreator listener){
    DirectMessageListenerContainer factory = new DirectMessageListenerContainer();
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setConnectionFactory(conn);
    factory.setConsumersPerQueue(5);
    factory.setMessageListener(listener);
    return factory;
}
```

As per my understanding, this will assign 5 consumers to each queue working on separate channel. for eg, if i add 5 queues to this bean so the total number of consumes will be 25 working on 5 different channels. My questions are:

1. What will be the impact of idle consumers on CPU in Cloud Foundry. In case some queues are having less messages, will the performance be impacted for the application as there will be some idle consumers?
2. Is there any way to define specific number of consumers of each queue separately?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idle consumers will use minimal resources (just a small amount of memory, no cpu). No, you can't specify consumer counts for each queue, unless you have a separate container for each.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for response. But if we add more container, will it become more memory consuming?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it's probably not significant; you can compare the difference if you really are concerned about it.

Comment: I'm really interested in the statement "Idle consumers will use minimal resources (just a small amount of memory, no cpu)". Would you be able to provide more details on that or a reference where I can read more about it please?

Comment: @GaryRussell under what conditions would you need to increase factory.setConsumersPerQueue(5); from the default value of 1 ? If consumerPerQueue is left at 1, and the default fetch size is 10, will 10 messages be processed simultaneously in 10 different threads, or will it be done sequentially from a buffer of 10. Thank you

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments to answers, especially those more than a year old; always asj a new question, which I see you did. I answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975870/proper-use-of-springrabbit-directmessagelistenercontainer-and-setconsumersperque/59976707#59976707). The prefetch size has no effect on concurrency; it is just that; prefetch.